# Slick Query Optimization

Tags: scala, slick, slick-3.0

I have the following Scala/Slick/PlayFramework code:

```
class UserRepository @Inject()(dbConfigProvider: DatabaseConfigProvider, loginInfoRepository: LoginInfoRepository) extends BaseRepository[UserTable, User](TableQuery[UserTable], dbConfigProvider.get[JdbcProfile].db) with UserQuery {

  val db = dbConfigProvider.get[JdbcProfile].db
  def findUserByProviderIdAndKey(providerId: String, providerKey: String): Future[User] = {
    for {
      maybeLoginInfo <- loginInfoRepository.findByProviderIdAndProviderKey(providerId, providerKey)
      maybeUser <- db.run(query.filter(_.loginId === maybeLoginInfo.loginId).result.head) //query refers to the user table with a loginId column
    } yield maybeUser

  }
```

Which queries a user table and a login_info table. The user table has a foreign key into login_info table.

Currently, the `findByProviderIdAndProviderKey` method returns a `Future[LoginInfo]`. However, I would like to change it to return a `Future[Option[LoginInfo]]` for user id's that don't exist. It can be easily changed in the `findByProviderIdAndProviderKey` method, but I'm not sure how the change for comprehension to deal with an option value.

I guess I could to something like below (needs refactoring):

```
    class UserRepository @Inject()(dbConfigProvider: DatabaseConfigProvider, loginInfoRepository: LoginInfoRepository) extends BaseRepository[UserTable, User](TableQuery[UserTable], dbConfigProvider.get[JdbcProfile].db) with UserQuery {

      val db = dbConfigProvider.get[JdbcProfile].db
      def findUserByProviderIdAndKey(providerId: String, providerKey: String): Future[User] = {
       loginInfoRepository.findByProviderIdAndProviderKey(providerId, providerKey).map{
       case (Some(x)) => db.run(query.fitler(_.loginId == x.loginInd).result.headOption)
       case None=> Option(None)
}
```

Now, I have the following questions:

1. How would you deal with the query not returning values for a given query? For instance, if the login information doesn't exist in the table? Am I doing it the right way? Or is there a better way?
2. I would have thought that slick caters for `Option` values automatically in joins, but seems like it does not. Why are `Option` values not lifted?
3. Would the above be translated into two SQL queries and database calls? If yes, how do I re-structure it so it only issues one database call with a proper join?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Since your question is about your `findByProviderIdAndProviderKey` method, could you also post the code for this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you only posted part of your code, I will try to construct an example based on your question.

According to your question `loginInfoRepository.findByProviderIdAndProviderKey` returns a `Future[LoginInfo]`, that means you already call `db.run` within that method. So to answer point 3: Yes, since you call `db.run` twice, it results in two roundtrips to your database.

Slicks queries are composable, so what you probably want to do is, use the query of `findByProviderIdAndProviderKey` within `findUserByProviderIdAndKey` and not the result:

```
def findUserByProviderIdAndKey(providerId: String, providerKey: String): Future[Option[User]] = {
    val userQuery = for {
      loginInfo <- loginInfoQuery if loginInfo.providerId === providerId && loginInfo.providerKey === providerKey
      user <- query if user.loginId === loginInfo.loginId
    } yield user

    db.run( userQuery.result.headOption )
}
```

The first line in the for comprehension queries all `LoginInfos` with the given parameters (I guessed your query and field names). 
The second line takes those `LoginInfos` and queries `Users` with the given `loginId`.

Now if the `loginInfoQuery` does not return anything, the second line will never be executed (the nature of the for comprehension) and slick will return nothing. 
If the first line returns something, but there is no `User` with the given `loginId`, slick will also return nothing. 
Only if both lines return something, slick will actually return values.

To return one option from the result set your use `userQuery.result.headOption`. You should never use `userQuery.result.head` unless you are 100% sure, that something will be returned (which you usually never can be).

This query will only hit the database once and will probably result in a joined query ( you would need to look at the created statement, to be sure ).

Comment: Thanks! I arrived at the same solution after trying a few things myself..but thanks for the answer. It is indeed what I was looking for.

Comment: apologies..I upvoted the answer but forgot to accept it..have accepted it now :-)